# Write GridView to .csv file c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, csv, streamwriter

I am working on developing a website where customers order directly from our website.  I had code working until a few days ago when I changed how the GridView was edited.  I had previously set the GridView to AutoGenerate Columns, and have changed that since I needed more functionality for the edit feature.  Here is how I create the table (created when user clicks a button to add a quick detail with the GridView):

```
 public void CreateTable()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            if (Session["table"] != null)
                table = (DataTable)Session["table"];
            else
            {
                table.Columns.Add("Part Number", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(Int32));
                table.Columns.Add("Ship-To", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("Requested Date", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("Shipping Method", typeof(string));
            }

            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["Part Number"] = part;
            row["Quantity"] = qty;
            row["Ship-To"] = shipto;
            row["Requested Date"] = reqdate;
            row["Shipping Method"] = shipmthd;
            table.Rows.Add(row);

            Session["table"] = table;
            griditems.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
            griditems.DataBind();
        }
        catch
        {
            //error message
        }
    }
```

This displays the Gridview and allows users to edit/delete the items as they choose.  Then I have another button that is displayed when the GridView is created that actually writes the .csv file to the server (my computer for the moment until deployment).  Here is the code for that:

```
protected void orderbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //ordernum++;
            //custordernum = ordernum.ToString("0000000");

            if (userlbl.Visible == false && userlbl2.Visible == false)
            {

                GlobalList.OnlineOrderNum.Add(custordernum, ordernum);
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Web_Order\Orders.Bin", FileMode.Create);
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(fs, GlobalList.OnlineOrderNum);
                fs.Close();
                fs.Dispose();

                ///Write CSV File For Order
                StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Web_Order\Order_W" + custordernum.ToString() + ".csv");
                foreach (GridViewRow row in griditems.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        // get cell's text
                        string cellText = cell.Text;
                        // add quotes and comma around value and append
                        strBuilder.Append("\"" + cellText + "\",");
                    }
                    strBuilder.Append("\n");
                }
                // output CSV result
                tw.Write(strBuilder.ToString());
                tw.Close();
                tw.Dispose();
                GlobalList.weborder = "W" + custordernum.ToString();

                Response.Redirect("~/OrderSubmitted.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                validatelbl.Text = "CANNOT SUBMIT FORM WITH ERRORS.  PLEASE CORRECT YOUR ERRORS BEFORE SUBMITTING.";
                validatelbl.Visible = true;
                userlbl.Text = "Please correct your table with the correct information before submitting your order";
                userlbl.Visible = true;
                userlbl2.Text = "Are your Part Numbers correct?  Are your Quantities in the correct format?";
                userlbl2.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //error message
        }
    }
```

Here's my edit/delete code for the GridView:

```
protected void griditems_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        griditems.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindData();
    }

    protected void griditems_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the edit index. 
        griditems.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        //Bind data to the GridView control. 
        BindData();
    }

    protected void griditems_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        //Reset the edit index.
        griditems.EditIndex = -1;
        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindData();
    }

    protected void griditems_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string valtext = "An error has occured, please check and make sure your editing is in the correct format and try again.";
        orderbtn.Visible = false;
        try
        {
            TextBox editpart = (TextBox)griditems.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("partedit");      
            TextBox editqty = (TextBox)griditems.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("qtyedit");
            TextBox editshipto = (TextBox)griditems.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("shiptoedit");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar editcal = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar)griditems.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("reqdatecaledit"); 
            DropDownList editshipmthd = (DropDownList)griditems.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("shipmthdedit"); 
            string newpart = editpart.Text.ToString();
            int newqty = Convert.ToInt32(editqty.Text);
            string newshipto = editshipto.Text.ToString();
            string newreqdate = editcal.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            string newshipmthd = editshipmthd.SelectedItem.ToString();

            //Reset date if calendar date is not changed so it is not null!
            if (newreqdate == "1/1/0001")
                newreqdate = reqdate;

            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["table"]; 

            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            dr["Part Number"] = newpart;
            dr["Quantity"] = newqty;
            dr["Ship-TO"] = newshipto;
            dr["Requested Date"] = newreqdate;
            dr["Shipping Method"] = newshipmthd;                
            dr.AcceptChanges();

            Session["table"] = dt;

            if (validatelbl.Text == valtext)
                validatelbl.Visible = false;

            griditems.EditIndex = -1;
            BindData();
            orderbtn.Visible = true;
        }
        catch
        {                
            validatelbl.Text = valtext;
            validatelbl.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void griditems_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //DataTable dt = table;
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["table"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dt.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex + griditems.PageIndex * 10);
                griditems.DataSource = dt;
                BindData();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            validatelbl.Text = "An error occured while processing your request deleting a record.  Please try again.";
            validatelbl.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Here's the aspx code for the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="griditems" runat="server" 
        onrowdeleting="griditems_RowDeleting" onrowediting="griditems_RowEditing" onrowupdating="griditems_RowUpdating"
                  AllowPaging="True" 
        onpageindexchanging="griditems_PageIndexChanging" Onrowcancelingedit="griditems_RowCancelingEdit" 
                  Caption="Order Details" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" >            
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#FF9900" BorderStyle="Double"/> 
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" />
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <Columns> 
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Part Number">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID = "partlbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Part Number") %>'></asp:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="partedit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Part Number")%>'  ></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID = "qtylbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="qtyedit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity")%>'  ></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ship-To">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID = "shiptolbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ship-To") %>'></asp:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="shiptoedit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ship-To")%>'  ></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Requested Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID = "reqdatelbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Requested Date") %>'></asp:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Calendar ID="reqdatecaledit" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" 
                              DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#003399" Height="200px" Width="220px" 
                              ondayrender="reqdatecal_DayRender" ShowGridLines="True">
                              <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" Height="1px" />
                              <DayStyle BackColor="White" />
                              <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
                              <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                              <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#FF9900" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                              <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
                              <TitleStyle BackColor="#003399" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" 
                                          Height="25px" />
                              <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="White" />
                              <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" /></asp:Calendar>
            </EditItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shipping Method">  
            <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="shipmthdlbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Shipping Method") %>'></asp:Label>   
            </ItemTemplate>              
              <EditItemTemplate>            
                <asp:DropDownList ID="shipmthdedit" runat="server">                
                  <asp:ListItem>FedEx Ground (1-5 Business Days)</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>FedEx 3 Business Days</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>FedEx 2 Business Days</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>FedEx Overnight</asp:ListItem>   
                </asp:DropDownList>    
              </EditItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>    
        </Columns>    
    </asp:GridView>
```

I don't understand why it was working all this time and now all of the sudden it is not working. It creates the file with the new ordernumber as it should, its just the .csv file is empty (no data at all) Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can correct your path, and replace TextWriter with StreamWriter

```
var path = Path.Combine("C:\Web_Order\Order_W",custordernum.ToString(),".csv");
StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@path);
```

Or use directly var.

```
var tw = new StreamWriter(@path);
```

Adjust your code with try catch block in order to treat exception if occurs

```
try
{

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  Console.Write(ex.Message); 
  throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using `TextWriter` here, and you don't need to redirect. Just write to `Response.Write()`.

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // No error so write as attachment
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=data.csv");

    // Write your output here
    Response.Write(...);

    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: I know I dont have to redirect, and I have tried this code...No luck.